# How to continouosly evaluate a tensorflow object detection model in parallel to training with model_main

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I successfully trained an object detection model with custom examples using `train.py` and `eval.py`. Running both programms in parallel I was able to visualize training and evaluation metrics in tensorboard during training.

However both programs were moved to the `legacy` folder and `model_main.py` seems to be the preferred way to run training and evaluation (by executing only a single process). However when I start `model_main.py` with the following `pipeline.config`:

```
train_config {
  batch_size: 1
  num_steps: 40000
  ...
}
eval_config {
  # entire evaluation set
  num_examples: 821
  # for continuous evaluation
  max_evals: 0
  ...
}
```

I see with enabled INFO logging in the output of `model_main.py` that training and evaluation are executed sequentially (as opposed to concurrently as before with two processes) and after every single training step a complete evaluation takes place.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving 'checkpoint_path' summary for global step 35932: ...
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 35933 into ...
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
...
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2018-08-30-10:06:47
...
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from .../model.ckpt-35933
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [82/821]
...
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [738/821]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [820/821]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [821/821]
...
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2018-08-30-10:29:35
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 35933: ...
INFO:tensorflow:Saving 'checkpoint_path' summary for global step 35933: .../model.ckpt-35933
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 35934 into .../model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
...
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2018-08-30-10:29:56
...
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from .../model.ckpt-35934
```

This of course slows down training in a way that almost no progress is made. When I reduce the evaluation steps with `model_main`'s command line parameter `--num_eval_steps` to `1` training is as fast as it was before (using `train.py` and `eval.py`), however the evaluation metrics become useless (e.g. the `DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP...` become constant and have values like `1`, `0` or even `-1`). To me it seems it is constantly computing these values for the same single image only.

So what is the right way to start `model_main.py` such that is does make reasonable fast progress and in parallel computes the evaluation metrics from the entire evaluation set.

Answer (score 2):

Inside training.py there's a class `EvalSpec` which is called in main_lib.py.
Its constructor has a parameter called `throttle_secs` which sets the interval between consequent evaluations and has a default value of 600, and it never gets a different value in model_lib.py.
If you have a specific value you want, you can simply change the default value,
but the better practice of course is to pass it as a parameter of model_main.py which will feed `EvalSpec` through model_lib.py.

In more details, set it as another input flag
`flags.DEFINE_integer('throttle_secs', <DEFAULT_VALUE>, 'EXPLANATION')`,
then
`throttle_secs=FLAGS.throttle_secs`,
and then change `model_lib.create_train_and_eval_specs` to also receive `throttle_secs`, and inside it, add it to the call of `tf.estimator.EvalSpec`.

EDIT:
I found out that you can also set `eval_interval_secs` in the eval_config of the .config file. In case this works (not all flags are supported since they moved from eval.py to model_main.py) - this is obviously a simpler solution. If not - use the solution above.

EDIT2: I tried using `eval_interval_secs` in eval_config, and it didn't work, so you should use the first solution.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and sorry for the delay. TBH I hoped for a solution where I do not need to change source code. That is why I asked how to start `model_main.py` and not how to modify it, but obviously this was not clear enough. Actually I found a different way with modifying source-code by changing the `RunConfig`s `save_checkpoints_steps` and `save_checkpoints_secs`. It gets passed to `model_lib`s `create_estimator_and_inputs` to create the `Estimator`. From my point of view the advantage is that I can control the evaluation interval in number of train steps as opposed to time.

Comment: This is indeed a possibility, but it makes you change the checkpoint saving frequency. If you're okay with it - then great.