# Tensorflow runs "Running per image evaluation" indefinitly

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am running my first tensorflow job (object detection training) right now, using the tensorflow API. I am using the ssd mobilenet network from the modelzoo. I used the >>ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync.config<< as a config-file and as a fine tune checkpoint the >>ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_300x300_coco14_sync_2018_07_03<< checkpoint.

I started my training with the following command:

```
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH='/my_path_to_tensorflow/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/models/model/ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync.config'
MODEL_DIR='/my_path_to_tensorflow/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/models/model/train'
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=200000
SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1
python object_detection/model_main.py \
--pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
--model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
--num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
--sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=$SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES \
--alsologtostderr
```

No coming to my problem, I hope the community can help me with. I trained the network over night and it trained for 1400 steps and then started evaluating per image, which was running the entire night. Next morning I saw, that network only evaluated and the training was still at 1400 steps. You can see part of the console output in the image below.

[Console output from evaluation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bGwl.png)

I tried to take control by using the eval config parameter in the config file.

```
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  num_examples: 5000
}
```

I added max_evals = 1, because the documentation says that I can limit the evaluation like this. I also changend eval_interval_secs = 3600 because I only wanted one eval every hour. Both options had no effect.

I also tried other config-files from the modelzoo, with no luck. I searched google for hours, only to find answers which told me to change the parameters I already changed. So I am coming to stackoverflow to find help in this Matter.

Can anybody help me, maybe hat the same experience? Thanks in advance for all your help!

#### Environment information

```
$ pip freeze | grep tensor
tensorboard==1.11.0
tensorflow==1.11.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.11.0

$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a solution for the problem. The problem with tensorflow 1.10 and after is, that you can not set checkpoint steps or checkpoint secs in the config file like before. By default tensorflow 1.10 and after saves a checkpoint every 10 min. If your hardware is not fast enough and you need more then 10 min for evaluation, you are stuck in a loop.

So to change the time steps or training steps till a new checkpoint is safed (which triggers the evaluation), you have to navigate to the model_main.py in the following folder:

> tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/

Once you opened model_main.py, navigate to line 62. Here you will find

> config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir)

To trigger the checkpoint save after 2500 steps for example, change the entry to this:

> config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,save_checkpoints_steps=2500).

Now the model is saved every 2500 steps and afterwards an evaluation is done.

There are multiple parameters you can pass through this option. You can find a documentation here:

> tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/run_config.py.

From Line 231 to 294 you can see the parameters and documentation.

I hope I can help you with this and you don't have to look for an answer as long as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that evaluation takes more than 10 minutes in your case? It could be that since 10 minutes is the default interval for making evaluation, it keeps evaluating.

Unfortunately, the current API doesn't easily support altering the time interval for evaluation.
By default, evaluation happens after every checkpoint saving, which by default is set to 10 minutes.
Therefore you can change the time for saving a checkpoint by specifying `save_checkpoint_secs` or `save_checkpoint_steps` as an input to the instance of MonitoredSession (or MonitoredTrainingSession). Unfortunately and best to my knowledge, these parameters are not available to be set as flags to model_main.py or from the config file. Therefore, you can either change their value by hard coding, or exporting them out so that they will be available.

An alternative way, without changing the frequency of saving a checkpoint, is modifying the evaluation frequency which is specified as `throttle_secs` to `tf.estimator.EvalSpec`.
See my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52425031/10263280) as to how to export this parameter to model_main.py.

Comment: Hello netanel-sam. Thank you so much for your quick an helpful answer. The only question that remains, is: I would like to use `save_checkpoint_steps`, do I replace `save_checkpoint_secs` with `save_checkpoint_steps`? Thank you very much! - Marcel

Comment: No. You can use either parameters to set the frequency of saving checkpoints, either by time (`secs`) or number of steps (`steps`). In order to change the default number you can modify the value inside training/monitored_session.py. Of course that the best practice is to set the parameter when you call the function instead of hard-coding it, but as I mentioned before, it's not very easy making it available to set from outside.

Comment: I changed the `save_checkpoint_secs` in the `monitored_session.py` in the function `MonitoredTrainingSession` to 5400, sadly no change.

Comment: `save_checkpoint_secs` or `save_checkpoint_steps` didn't help me. Any other ideas?